# Making a method generate a new number every time it is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

goal: I'm trying to make it so when self.damage is called it generates a random number between 1 and the argument "damage". However this random number is only being picked the first time, and then used throughout the entire code. My current code looks like this:

```
import random
class PC(object): 
  def __init__(self, health, damage):
    self.health = health 
    self.damage = random.randint(1,damage)

Player_character = PC(10,5) 
Spider = PC(2,3)
print(Player_character.health)

def fightspider(spiderturn):
  rounds = 0
  while spiderturn == 1 and rounds < 2:
    Spider.damage
    Player_character.health = Player_character.health - Spider.damage
    rounds += 1
    print(Spider.damage)
print(Player_character.health)

def fightplayer(playerturn):
  if playerturn == 1:
    Spider.damage
fightspider(1)
```

When I say Spider.damage inside of the while loop I want it to select a new random number, currently it is only using the first one and not picking any new ones.
I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix, can I get any leads on where to go with this?
This is my first time using classes so I'm still only halfway sure on how exactly they work!
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You [chose a random number once](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Answer (score 0):

The damage is only be called in the initalizer of the class `random.randint(1, damage)` (in the `__init__`). I recommend you only initialize the `max_damage` in your initalizer then create a new function that will generate the damage for example:

```
import random

class PC(object): 
    def __init__(self, health, damage):
        self.health = health 
        self.max_damage = max_damage

    def get_damage():
         return random.randint(1, self.max_damage)
```

Then instead of `Spider.damage` you can use `Spider.get_damage()` to get the damage generated everytime. Hope this makes sense, good luck on your programming endeavors!

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this question with "python-3.x", so I presume you're using 3.x

You're using`Spider.damage` in two different ways:

1. You're using it as an expression that returns the current value stored in the `damage` attribute.
2. You're also expectng it to act  as a function call that will somehow call `random.randint()` and re-assign a new random number to the `damage` attribute.

The first usage is ok. The second won't work.

I suggest you write a method called `set_damage()`, that will internally call 
`random.randint()`, and update the `damage` attribute.